# Routing example.at to S3 bucket and *.example.at to load balancer with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have set up a multi tenant application which should be available to clients via a subdomain (e.g. https://client1.example.at). Requests to *.example.at are routed to a load balancer via Route 53. The load balancer has an AWS signed wildcard certificate (e.g. supporting example.at and *.example.at). From this side, everything is working as expected and I can access https://client1.example.at, https://client2.example.at, etc.

Based on this setup, I wanted to route specific request without subdomain (except www) such as https://www.example.at or https://example.at to a bucket (which is also named www.example.com) and not to the load balancer (I just want to serve a static site for requests to the "main domain"). It works but I can only access www.example.at and example.at without using HTTPS. My setup can be seen below:

[image: Route 53 Configuration]

I then found out that I have to use Cloudfront in order to use HTTPS for a custom domain with S3 buckets (if that is correct?). Now I have a few questions:

1. Is it necessary to use Cloudfront to serve content from my S3 bucket for www.example.at and example.at via HTTPS?
2. If Cloudfront is necessary then I have to request a new certificate for www.example.at and example.at in region US EAST according to the [official AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-cf.html). Is it possible to create two certificates for the same domain with AWS certificate manager or can I get some conflicts with this setup?
3. Is it ok to use *.example.at as A type record with alias to the load balancer at all?
4. Generally speaking, is my Route 53 setup valid at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to route specific request without subdomain (except www) such as https://www.example.com or https://example.com to a bucket (which is also named www.example.com)

Each of those "domains" must route to a different bucket unless you are using a proxy (which reroutes the hostname passed from the browser) in front of S3, the domain name must match the bucket name. If they don't then your requests are going to a bucket matching the DNS name you routed from, the routing has nothing to do with the hostname of the S3 bucket endpoint.

In other words, let's say your hostname was www.example.com, and you set the CNAME to example.com.s3.amazonaws.com (or you could use the website endpoint, it doesn't matter for this example).

When a request hits the DNS name www.example.com it then is sent to the S3 server which is behind the S3 hostname. That request **from the browser is for hostname "www.example.com"**, the actual CNAME referenced which pointed to the S3 endpoint is irrelevant because S3 never knows what actual CNAME was used to by your browser to connect to S3. So S3 will attempt to pull the requested object from the www.example.com bucket.

URL -> S3 Bucket

- https://www.example.com -> s3://www.example.com
- https://example.com -> s3://example.com

> It works but I can only access www.example.at and example.at without using HTTPS.

CNAME DNS routing like this when using SSL to an S3 bucket does not work. The reason for this is that the S3 wild card certificates are 1 level deep (*.s3.amazonaws.com) so your bucket www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com will fail to match it because it has 2 extra levels above the wild card. So your browser rejects the certificate as invalid for the hostname.

To accomplish this you must use a proxy of some sort in front of S3 with your own certificates for the domain in question.

> Is it necessary to use Cloudfront to serve content from my S3 bucket for www.example.at and example.at via HTTPS?

CloudFront is an excellent option for addressing the HTTPS with CNAME routed DNS to an S3 bucket issue we just mentioned.

> If Cloudfront is necessary then I have to request a new certificate for www.example.at and example.at in region US EAST according to the official AWS docs. Is it possible to create two certificates for the same domain with AWS certificate manager or can I get some conflicts with this setup?

I can't answer that one, I can only suggest you try and find out what happens. If it doesn't work then it's not an option. It shouldn't take much time to figure this one out.

> Is it ok to use *.example.at as A type record with alias to the load balancer at all?

To clarify, an A Record can only ever be an IP address, an A Alias is similar to a CNAME (but is Route53 specific).

I highly recommend CNAMES (or ALIASES, they are similar). Pointing directly at one of S3's A-Records is a bad idea because you don't know if or when that IP will be removed from service. By referencing the hostname with a CNAME/ALIAS you don't have to worry about that. Unless you can be 100% sure that the IP will remain available then you shouldn't reference it.

> Generally speaking, is my Route 53 setup valid at all?

I don't see any issues with it, based on what you described it sounds like like things are working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

> If Cloudfront is necessary then I have to request a new certificate for www.example.at and example.at in region US EAST according to the official AWS docs. Is it possible to create two certificates for the same domain with AWS certificate manager or can I get some conflicts with this setup?

As suggested by @JoshuaBriefman I simply tried to create another certificate for the same domain in another region now and it worked. I could also use the certificate for the CloudFront distribution (additional certificate was created in US EAST) and all works now without any problems so far.